# Clockwise right hand turn angle in 2D?

Tags: c#, math, geometry

If I have two points p1 and p2 where p1 is the pivot point and p2 is the original direction the user was headed and they have a number of possible directions to go p3...pn in random sequence. How do I get the angles between the choices and the segment formed by p1,p2 as clockwise(right hand) positive values between 0 and 360 so that I can sort them from least to greatest?

Also the points p1...pn will be in any quadrant, I can’t assume they will always be in the positive x,y direction. The grid is a standard Cartesian grid not screen coordinates so Y gets smaller as you go down not larger.

So in this example (sorry for the poor drawing but Paint was all I had on my laptop) I need to get the angles:

[image: Grid showing the points and angles]

(p2-p1-p3)
( p2-p1-p4)
( p2-p1-p5)
( p2-p1-p6)

In this order(smallest right hand turn to largest right hand turn):
[( p2-p1-p4), ( p2-p1-p6), ( p2-p1-p5), (p2-p1-p3)]

The points in my case are a class called Vertex:

```
public class Vertex
{
    public double X = 0;
    public double Y = 0;
    public Vertex() { }
    public Vertex(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
 }
```

And the code for getting the angles and sorting looks like this right now but has a problem:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Vertex> SortByAngle(Vertex original, Vertex pivot, List<Vertex> choices)
    {
        choices.Sort((v1, v2) => GetTurnAngle(original, pivot, v1).CompareTo(GetTurnAngle(original, pivot, v2)));
        return choices;
    }

    private static double GetTurnAngle(Vertex original, Vertex pivot, Vertex choice)
    {
        var a = original.X - pivot.X;
        var b = original.Y - pivot.Y;
        var c = choice.X - pivot.X;
        var d = choice.Y - pivot.Y;

        var rads = Math.Acos(((a * c) + (b * d)) / ((Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)) * (Math.Sqrt(c * c + d * d))));

        return (180 / Math.PI * rads);

    }
```

The problem is the above is if I check it for:
original 66,-66
pivot 280,-191
choice 200,-180

I get an angle of 22.460643124 instead of 337.539356876 which means it went counter-clockwise from the original direction to get that angle. I need it to always go clockwise to get the angle.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Update: OK so according to what you guys are saying I can probably use some cross product like math to determine CW vs CCW so the new method would look like this:

```
    private static double GetTurnAngle(Vertex original, Vertex pivot, Vertex choice)
    {
        var a = original.X - pivot.X;
        var b = original.Y - pivot.Y;
        var c = choice.X - pivot.X;
        var d = choice.Y - pivot.Y;


        var angle = Math.Acos(((a * c) + (b * d)) / ((Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)) * (Math.Sqrt(c * c + d * d))));
        angle = (180 / Math.PI * angle);


        var z = (choice.X - pivot.X) * (original.Y - pivot.Y) - (choice.Y - pivot.Y) * (original.X - pivot.X);
        if (z < 0)
        {
            return 360 - angle;
        }
        return angle;

    }
```

Update 2:

Using the accepted solution it now looks like so:

```
    private static double GetTurnAngle(Vertex original, Vertex pivot, Vertex choice)
    {

        var angle1 = Math.Atan2(original.Y - pivot.Y, original.X - pivot.X);
        var angle2 = Math.Atan2(choice.Y - pivot.Y, choice.X - pivot.X);
        var angleDiff = (180 / Math.PI * (angle2 - angle1));

        if (angleDiff > 0)//It went CCW so adjust
        {
            return 360 - angleDiff;
        }
        return -angleDiff;//I need the results to be always positive so flip sign

    }
```

So far as I can tell that works great so far. Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: Is p2 a point or a direction (e.g. a vector)? The first sentence is inconclusive.

Comment: The actual angle of difference is the 22 degrees, not 337.  You will need to use 360 - Result if you wish to start at 360 instead of 0.

Comment: It seems you are only off by a plus/minus sign somewhere - have you tried cycling through permutations of the assignments to `a` through `d`? I realize the ideal solution is to know why the math is wrong but if it works ...

Comment: @norlesh It seems as though the answer is correct, and the expectations of the answer are not.  Viewing the picture attached to the OP shows that the angle should be between 0-90.

Comment: @KSdev I'm just doing some light reading, my brains to fried at this time of morning to actually perform trig 7;^)

Comment: @norlesh I'm working with Compasses at the moment so this kind of math won't leave me alone! :)

Comment: As I understand the problem (example: for original, pivot, choices of: (-5,0), (0, 0), (-3, 2); you get 33.7 CW and 326.3 CCW; or viceversa in case of interchanging the original and choices vertices), I can only see a casuistic solution based on quadrants (location of each point with respect to the others) to undoubtedly tell what value should be outputted. Perhaps there is a library (or a .NET function) but I am not aware about that.

Comment: @KSDev if the user is standing at 280,-191, and is facing 66,-66 they must turn 337 degrees to the right to be facing 200, -180 because only right hand (clockwise) turns are allowed. I need the clockwise turn angle and the method shown gives counter clockwise in this scenario. I'd be fine with it if it gave me an indication that it had done so via sign or something but it gives positive results for both so I have no way of correcting a left hand turn to be a right hand one.

Comment: PS: logically, you can rely on trigonometry (instead of in casuistic approaches; but I usually prefer the casuistic ones) and, for example, create a line between the two points (original and choices); another line from the pivot vertex to this line and deduce the situation from the angles between both lines (what, actually, is also kind of casuistic).

Comment: @user3159473 They do not turn 337 degrees CW.  They turn 22 degrees.  Round your #s and lets make it simple, you are at point `A` (100,-100) facing point `B` (25,-25) and turn to point `C` (75,-75).  Those are 3 points, which form a triangle.  A triangle's interior angles are 180 degrees.  It would be impossible to reach the 337 degrees.  If my understanding of your problem is correct you want the angle between point `B` and `C` while viewing from `A`?

Comment: @KSdev you are not understanding the point rightly (test the code to get clearer ideas); he is only considering two points (original and choices), pivot represents the reference point for the turn, that is, 0.0 for standard angle calculations. Its function does not output bigger than 180 angles and thus he should perform the corresponding correction (angle - 360) when required; but in case of always wanting to perform the calculations clockwisely, he would certainly get angles above 180 (refer to my example above).

Comment: @varocarbas yes, that is correct, I guess a better way for me to say it would have been I need the clockwise only rotation to go from facing the one way to facing the other so my possibilities are from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: @norlesh this is exactly what the OP is asking: how to make sure that the calculations are performed such that the turn between the first angle to the second one is always performed clockwisely; but there is no straightforward way to determine that.

Comment: As explained in my comments above: you can do it casuistically (e.g., function taking the three points as arguments and telling if the standard calculations are done clockwisely or not) or even by bringing some trigonometry into the picture. Simple example to understand this: if first point is on left/same height that pivot and the second point is above the first point, the calculations shouldn't be modified; in the same scenario, if the second point's Y value is lower than the first point's one, the angle calculated by your function should be corrected with -360.

Comment: This is not a straightforward implementation (that's why I haven't written an answer); but, as said, there might be a library or a .NET function performing it. Just wait and some help might come.

Comment: @user3159473 I think what you are doing is correct and adding a little intelligence to determine if the angle it is supplying is CCW or CW is all you need.  varocarbas had a nice simple approach with looking at the difference between the X/Y values for the 2 points, this will tell you if the angle value returned is right or left from your pivot point.  If left then just use 360-value.

Comment: @varocarbas I posted an updated method. I haven't tested it yet but does that look like what you were thinking?

Comment: Actually weston has posted an excellent answer; I did misunderstand initially. Atan2 accounts for both the value (as Atan) and the sign; his code delivers and excellent way to track the orientation and the value.

Comment: Regarding your correction; I did mean something on these lines (although didn't test it; I assume that it works fine; although seems a bit too simple, bear in mind that these kind of things can become tricky), but didn't want to spend the time in coming up with the solution (and validating it), mainly when I wasn't sure if there wasn't something in place like what weston has proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [atan2 function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It takes delta y and delta x, so can distinguish all angles.

```
angle1 = atan2(p1.y-p0.y, p1.x-p0.x);
angle2 = atan2(p2.y-p0.y, p2.x-p0.x);
angle = angle2 - angle1;
```

If angle is negative, then CW, if positive CCW (or other way around depending on your axis orientation). Note `|angle|` may be `> 180`, in which case you may want to do `360-|angle|` and reverse the CW CCW conclusion if you're after the shortest route.

Comment: Make sure you keep in mind the results of `atan2` are (-180,180), so if you want 360 you will have to adjust (-180, 0) to fit (180,360)

Comment: @varocarbas atan2 gives the full range of angles, therefore you can use it for CW/CCW

Comment: @varocarbas I have put up an example. I disagree that you cannot tell which angle atan2 is providing you. It's always either CW or CCW (depending on your axis orientation), but it's never both. The key thing is you give atan2 **two** arguments, not one ratio.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine... impressive! the power of the Atan + signs! not aware about this function! Big +1 for you and delete my comments right away.

Comment: @weston thank you! That sign flipping power of Atan2 is exactly what I needed. I marked this as the answer and updated the post. Is there anything more I need to do to process this question as answered? I just joined the site so I am not familiar with what all needs to be done.

Comment: @AndyTheCornbread that's all you need to do to accept the answer. You can upvote in addition though, the grey up arrow.

Comment: @varocarbas yeah it's a very useful function, many languages have it such as java.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I did a small research after seeing your code (not exactly C#). Note that I dismissed your solution right away because of assuming that was a variation of Atan, delivering more or less the same functionality (and thus not suitable for this situation). A pretty bad behaviour (assuming that something was wrong without even understanding it and, on top of everything, when I was precisely looking for a function performing these actions). Also another curious fact is that I have implemented various approaches in the past taking care of this issue, but every time custom-made.

Answer (score 0):

You find the Dn=direction from p1 to pn (x=pn.x-p1.x and y=pn.y-p1.y) by the formula:

Dn=f(x,y)=180-90*(1+sign(y))* (1-sign(x^2))-45*(2+sign(y))*sign(x)

```
     -180/pi()*sign(x*y)*atan((abs(y)-abs(x))/(abs(y)+abs(x)))
```

So the angles are Angle(p2-p1-pn)=Dn-D2.